# Postback fires before validation when using CustomValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I have made a simple project to explain my problem.

This is my Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"        
Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator    ID="cusDate" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ValidateEmptyText="true" 
                                OnServerValidate="DateValidate" 
                                ValidationGroup="DateVal" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtDate" 
                                ErrorMessage="Date error"></asp:CustomValidator>

        <asp:ImageButton        ID="btnSaveDate" 
                                CausesValidation="true" 
                                ValidationGroup="DateVal" 
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/save_32.png" 
                                runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)  <<<<<<BREAKPOINT 1 HERE
            {
            }
        }

        protected void DateValidate(Object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;  <<<<<<BREAKPOINT 2 HERE
        }
    }
}
```

I set two breakpoints, as shown above, and run the application. When I click "btnSaveDate" it first stops at breakpoint 1 and then at breakpoint 2. I thought it would stop at breakpoint 2 first, then reload the page and then stop at breakpoint 1.

Is there something wrong in the code or should it behave like this?

I have read many articles about this and tried a lot of different solutions, but no one has worked so far.

Comment: Thank you voddy and Rafa, but how should I do so that validation occurs before the page is reloaded? If using RequiredValidator the validation occurs before the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the *Postback event handling* happens **after** the *Load* event.

> If the request is a postback, control event handlers are called. After
>   that, the Validate method of all validator controls is called, which
>   sets the IsValid property of individual validator controls and of the
>   page. (There is an exception to this sequence: the handler for the
>   event that caused validation is called after validation.)

A *postback* means that a client is making an http request to the server and, every time a request arrives to the server, the *Page Life Cycle* stages are executed in this exact order. So the second answer is no, is not possible to enter in the breakpoint 2 then before entering the breakpoint 1.